# Getting Microsoft Team Meetings Using the Graph API

Tags: api, rest, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am getting all Teams meetings using the Microsoft Graph API but I don't find any API on the Microsoft documentation website someone suggests me any link how did I get all previous meetings using team API

Comment: What Teams API are you using?

Comment: graph API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: @sumairkhan - Could you please elaborate more on your issue?

Comment: can I get all meetings of the specific user using team graph API?

Comment: Please use punctuation marks when asking a question (or anywhere else, for that matter). It really makes it easier for people to get your point quickly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [List events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get a list of event objects in the user's mailbox. The list contains single instance meetings and series masters.